# cannot create wall posts with fb_graph

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rubygems, fb-graph

i am attempting to create a test user, and then write on that user's
wall. here is my code followed by the error i get (i'm using ruby and the gem fb_graph):

---

```
app = FbGraph::Application.new(config[:client_id], :secret =>
config[:client_secret])

user1 = app.test_user!(:installed => true, :permissions
=> :publish_stream)
user2 = app.test_user!(:installed => true, :permissions
=> :publish_stream)

me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)

me.feed!(:message => "Testing")
FbGraph::Unauthorized: FbGraph::Unauthorized    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/
1.8/gems/fb_graph-1.9.4/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:126:in
'handle_httpclient_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/fb_graph-1.9.4/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:
115:in 'handle_response'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/fb_graph-1.9.4/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:
48:in 'post'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/fb_graph-1.9.4/lib/fb_graph/
connections/feed.rb:15:in `feed!'
    from (irb):90
```

---

publish_stream should give me the proper permissions to write to the
wall, but as you can see, it doesn't.

any suggestions?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your access token is valid? Facebook needs a valid access token or it will not allow you to use the user's permissions, even if he granted them to you on facebook.